# Mac Excel 2011 VBA Evaluate

Tags: excel, vba, macos, evaluate, excel-2011

I am moving a excel VBA from PC to Mac and one line has an Evaluate function, for example:

```
Public Function test()

    test = Evaluate("=2+2")

End Function
```

However, if I try and run the macro on the mac the function returns #name. Is there an equivalent function on the Mac side to Evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the above function.

If you are calling the above function in VBA then it works as expected and If you are using it as a UDF i.e you are calling it from the worksheet then `#Name` error means that you have not pasted the function in a module. Move the function from the Sheet/Workbook code area into a module and then try again.

[image]